# Filter Array of Arrays To Retain Only Elements With Latest Dates Per ID

Tags: javascript, array-filter

How to filter this array

```
    var arr = [[1, "3/20/2018", "A"], [1, "3/20/2018", "B"], 
               [1, "4/20/2018", "A"], [1, "4/20/2018", "B"], 
               [2, "1/30/2018", "A"], [2, "1/30/2018", "B"], 
               [2, "3/30/2018", "A"], [2, "3/30/2018", "B"]
              ];
```

I want to filter only the elements with the latest dates per other sub-elements (ID) . To have this output:

```
var result = [[1, "4/20/2018", "A"], [1, "4/20/2018", "B"],
              [2, "3/30/2018", "A"], [2, "3/30/2018", "B"]
             ];
```

Comment: You're not including only the elements with the latest date - you also have `3/30/2018` included for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean `latest` dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations/assumptions

1. There were missing quotes around the date `3/20/2018`. Without quotes this will only be a floating number
2. Your sub-array has 3 items, where the first and last items form a unique combination (ID).

Based on the above, you can try following

```js
var arr = [[1, "3/20/2018", "A"], [1, "3/20/2018", "B"], [1, "4/20/2018", "A"], [1, "4/20/2018", "B"], [2, "1/30/2018", "A"], [2, "1/30/2018", "B"], [2, "3/30/2018", "A"], [2, "3/30/2018", "B"]];
             
   var obj = {};
   
   arr.forEach(function(item){
     var id = item[0] + "_" + item[2];
     if(obj[id]) {
       if(new Date(item[1]) > new Date(obj[id][1])) {
          obj[id] = item;  
       }
     } else {
       obj[id] = item;
     }
  });
   
  console.log(Object.values(obj));
```